# JavaScriptCore libpas scavenger error on Obfuscated IPA

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, obfuscation, ixguard

I am trying to open a website with WebKit integration in my app but I am getting **JavaScriptCore libpas scavenger** error when I pressed the open button.

I could not debug this problem because I am getting this error only with obfuscated IPA.

From the firebase Crashlytics, all error log is:

```
JavaScriptCore libpas scavenger

0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x141c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x806c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2  JavaScriptCore                 0xf3ba8 scavenger_thread_main + 1164
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc _pthread_start + 148
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8
```

Anyone else has had a similar problem as well? I could not find how to solve this issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this doesn't look like a crash, merely one of the threads. Post the whole crash dump

Comment: Thanks, @sfgblackwarkrts, I cannot see other crash logs because all of them are hidden. So I think, I will fix this issue first.

Comment: in what you posted there's nothing to "fix", it's a normal JavaScript cleanup process on WKWebView